# How to re-install grub boot loader in Windows?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I just install Windows 8 without effecting Ubuntu. But it directly boot into Windows 8. How can I re-install grub boot loader?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link to recover Grub:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

I would try using "boot repair". For all my boot problems the default setting has worked for me. From blank grub screens on a 12 year old computer to booting from a windows 7 install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Basically you will boot from a live dvd/usb and install boot-repair via this command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

and select recommended repair. I will uninstall and reinstall grub, so if windows removed it, this will fix it.

Again, for me this has been the easiest way.